# Generics type return type error: required type T, provided MyObject

Tags: java, generics

Hi I have some classes that declared like:

```java
class SuperObject {

}

class SuperClass<T extends SuperObject> {

}

class MyObject extends SuperObject {

}

class MyClass<T extends SuperObject> extends SuperClass<T> {

    protected T method() {
        return new MyObject();   // error: required type T, provided MyObject
    }

}
```

May I know what is wrong with this code? Why can't I return `MyObject`? how can I fix it?

Comment: Because let's say you had another class `MyOtherObject extends SuperObject`. In that case, an instance of `MyClass<MyOtherObject>` would have a `method()` that's expected to return an instance of `MyOtherObject`, but you've given it  `MyObject`.

Comment: @JacobG. Ah I see, sorry I did not realize that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do something like this:

```
abstract class SuperClass<T extends SuperObject> {
    abstract T method();
}

class MyObject extends SuperObject { }

class MyClass extends SuperClass<MyObject> {
    protected MyObject method() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

The supertype defines a generic type which a specific type uses with a particular qualified type. In this case, the `SuperClass` uses a generic type, that has to be a covariant type of `SuperObject`. The `MyClass` extends such superclass and implements such abstract method using its specific type `MyObject`, therefore the return type of the method is `MyObject`.

> Why can't I return MyObject? how can I fix it?

You can derive it from my text above. `MyObject` is simply not assignable to `T` because the compiler cannot predict the `T` will be in runtime.